# How to insert two or more records from a 'unique' field in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables

```
 CREATE TABLE persona( 
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nombre VARCHAR(30),
 apPaterno VARCHAR(30), 
 ine VARCHAR(12) unique);
 
 CREATE TABLE cliente( cuenta INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 saldoapertura DOUBLE,
 fechaRegistro DATE, 
 sucursal VARCHAR(30), 
 idPersona int, 
 FOREIGN KEY(idPersona) REFERENCES persona(id));
```

It is about simulating a bank, in which the identification is unique for each person (ine), I want to know if there is a way to insert a person with different accounts several times.  Even if the 'unique' clause exists in the (ine) field.

The stored procedure is this:

```
delimiter ##
 create procedure sp_aperturaCuenta(
    IN p_nombre varchar(30),
    in p_apellidoPaterno varchar (30),
    in p_ine varchar (12),
    in p_cuenta int,
    in p_saldoApertura double,
    in p_sucursal varchar (30)
 )
 begin
 declare id int;
 declare fallo boolean default  0; 
 declare continue handler for sqlexception
 begin
 set fallo = 1;
 end;
 start transaction;
 
 insert  into persona (nombre, apPaterno, ine) values (p_nombre,p_apellidoPaterno, p_ine);
    set id = last_insert_id();
    insert  into cliente values (p_cuenta,p_saldoApertura, curdate(), p_sucursal, id ); 
   
    if fallo = 0 then
    commit; 
    else
    rollback;
    end if;
 end ##
 delimiter ;
```

Here are the calls to the procedure:

```
Call sp_aperturaCuenta('Carlos','Montes','12302002120',1121,1000,'Delta'); 
Call sp_aperturaCuenta('Carlos','Montes','12302002120',1231,5000,'Delta');
```

As can be seen, the only difference between one call and another is that the account is different. And I can't insert the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a second `cliente` record for an existing `persona`, rename your `id` variable to `v_id`:

```
declare v_id int;
```

Then try to lookup the `persona` by `ine` and insert only if you cannot find a record.

```
    select id into v_id from persona where ine = p_ine;
    if v_id is null then 
      insert  into persona (nombre, apPaterno, ine) values (p_nombre,p_apellidoPaterno, p_ine);
      set v_id = last_insert_id();
    end if;
    insert  into cliente values (p_cuenta,p_saldoApertura, curdate(), p_sucursal, v_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique **constraint** is a **constraint** for a reason and RBDMs are excellent at following **constraints**.

As long as you have the unique **constraint** in your table definition, the column for which the unique **constraint** is defined for cannot have multiple equal values.

The only way to bypass the constraint is to **remove** it, which is not what I'm suggesting if it confronts the requirements for your DB design.